# SQL WHERE Help: Pulling Data Multiple Rows

Tags: sql

I want to pull, say, all rows where a User has Color=blue and Color=red. I am interested in pulling these multiple rows to determine which users CHANGED their Color from blue to red, or from red to blue.

The general query i have now is this. What is wrong and how can i improve it? thank you!

Does this return Zero results because I am asking that the row's value has BOTH blue and red at the same time? (which is impossible)
my other worry, is that if I use OR instead of AND, that i will include rows for users that are color blue, or color red, but did NOT change between the two colors.

I want the results to ONLY show rows 1 and 4

```
SELECT *
FROM Table a
WHERE a.color='blue'
AND a.color='red'
```

Table Structure is below

```
Row  |  Date  |  Userid  |  Session  |  Color
1    |  11/1  |   001    |     24    |  Blue        
2    |  11/2  |   002    |     25    |  Green
3    |  11/2  |   003    |     26    |  Yellow
4    |  11/6  |   001    |     32    |  Red
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question an hour ago? [clicky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154571/sql-where-help-how-do-i-pull-data-from-multiple-rows-in-one-single-query)

Answer (score 0):

The glaring problem is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table a
WHERE a.color='Blue'
OR a.color='Red'
```

You will either need a field with the previous color to be stored (kind of like a history) if you wish because otherwise there's not enough information in the database to properly assess what colors have been changed from.